# Assistance with SUMIF(?) in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a data set where some of the IDs have been changed to an existing ID. For these cases, I want to update the old volume with the sum of the old and new. I've tried to mix together Index matches and Sumifs but I haven't had any success.

What's the easiest way to do this?

[image: Sample Data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following in `E2` and drag down:

```
=IF(D2<>"",0,B2+IFERROR(SUMIFS($B$2:$B$7,$D$2:$D$7,C2),0))
```

This will:

- If there is a new ID (`D2`) then result in a `0`
- If not, then add the volume of the current row (`B2`) together with the SUM of the volume where the ID 2 matches the current row's ID 1 (`SUMIFS($B$2:$B$7,$D$2:$D$7,C2)`)